# Passing a TForm/form as a parameter with dynamically created images on it

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have an object called eventsobj. In one of its procedures It draws a few dynamic images onto a form. So far it works. However for neatness and because my teacher told me to my object is in a separate unit.

What I would ideally like is for the object to have a function that returns a TForm, which I will then set to the main form.
In my other unit:

```
    Function drawNewForm(numberOfImages : integer) : TForm1;
```

In my main form:

```
    NewForm := TForm1.create;
    NewForm := drawNewForm(10);
    CurrentForm := newform;
```

Sorry it's vague but all I need is the principle not necessarily the code.
When I tried these few lines the current form didn't change at all.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your teacher will be satisfied if you just move everything (including the form) to a new unit... you could as well rename the unit. hehehe.

I believe what your teacher meant is that your eventsobj class should be in another unit, and you should instantiate it in your main form. You would have something like this:

YourNewUnit.pas:

```
unit YourNewForm;

...

type
  TYourClass = class(...)

...
```

MainForm.pas:

```
unit MainForm;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, YourNewUnit;

...

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    with TYourClass.Create(Self) do begin
        Parent := Self; //If needed...
        //Other initialization stuff
    end;
end;
```

You could also create a private field on the form to hold the reference to your `TYourClass` instance if you need to call it later on the code. This would look like this:

```
unit MainForm;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, YourNewUnit;

type
    TForm1 = class(TForm)
    private
        FYourClass: TYourClass;

...

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    FYourClass := TYourClass.Create(Self);
    with FYourClass do begin
        Parent := Self; //If needed...
        //Other initialization stuff
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I see why I must use a second unit now. However where do I create the images? (Main form or newunit) I only ask this because my object is supposed to create the images

Comment: @user3457105 If I understood well, the images belong to your new object. So you must create the images in it. Your object should be self-contained. If you ever want to use this same object in another form (or even another application), it should work.

Comment: oh I see. how would I save the images? array of TImage?

Comment: @user3457105 if you want your images to be built-in inside your executable, you should probably add it in your application resources and load on object creator... that's a different question, though, and you should open a new one if you have trouble with that part.

Comment: alright. thanks for all the help GabrielF!